# Does Samsung Galaxy support MMS?

Tags: mms

Does Samsung Galaxy support MMS? I have got Galaxy 1.8 version mobile. MMS is not sending in it.

Comment: have you tried on any other phone? are you trying with your code, or just the MMS stock app? which country, service provider, etc.?

Comment: Which flavor of Galaxy? There are quite a few devices under that monicker.

Comment: I am using Samsung Galaxy Ace. And since I purchased, I cant send any MMS. I have to check with provider about its settings. It's surely setting issue.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Samsung Galaxy 3 with Android 2.1 update
MMS works in this.

Comment: Thanks..Almost all samsung supports Android OS..In my case Use package data is not given at first..

Answer (score 1):

If you are having problems sending MMS, perhaps its not the OS or the hardware, but a setting or you provider?  I was having issues sending texts on my Captivate (Galaxy S), turned out AT&T had not turned messaging on for my plan, and I had to enter a Message Center number (Messaging app -> Menu -> Settings -> Message center) to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

All models of the Samsung Galaxy support MMS messaging.  This includes the original "Galaxy" to the very latest models.

When having such an issue, it's almost always a configuration issue, either in the phone itself or with the service provider.